# Python Import User Agent gives Unresolved reference 'UserAgent'

Tags: python, installation, package, user-agent

I want generate a random user agent. I found this website: https://pypi.org/project/random-user-agent/
I did the pip install, copied the code and pasted it in my script.
But a Unresolved reference 'UserAgent' error appeared. I can install the package successfully but nothing changes and the same errors appears.
What am I doing wrong?

```
from random_user_agent.user_agent import UserAgent
from random_user_agent.params import SoftwareName, OperatingSystem
software_names = [SoftwareName.CHROME.value]
operating_systems = [OperatingSystem.WINDOWS.value, 
OperatingSystem.LINUX.value]

user_agent_rotator = UserAgent(software_names=software_names, 
operating_systems=operating_systems, limit=100)

user_agents = user_agent_rotator.get_user_agents()
```

And the error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/pilsp/Documents/Python Scripts/Amazon_Monitor/monitor.py", 
line 119, in <module>
from random_user_agent.user_agent import UserAgent
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'random_user_agent'
```

[Here is a picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8x5R.png)

This is what I get when I type in cmd pip show random-user-agent and python --version

```
C:\Users\pilsp>pip show random-user-agent
Name: random-user-agent
Version: 1.0.1
Summary: A package to get random user agents based filters provided by user
Home-page: https://github.com/Luqman-Ud-Din/random_user_agent
Author: Luqman-Ud-Din Muhammad
Author-email: luqmanuddinm@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: 
c:\users\pilsp\documents\htl\4bhif\sonstiges\autoclicker\venv\lib\site- 
packages
Requires:
Required-by:

C:\Users\pilsp>python --version
Python 3.8.6
```

Comment: Don't post code as image links; that just makes it harder for us to help.  Please update the question and put the code, and the full error traceback message, as text.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated it.

Comment: Update the question to show us the output of these commands: `pip show random-user-agent` and `python --version`

Comment: Thanks, I done this

Comment: It looks like the `random-user-agent` module is installed inside a virtual environment.  Did you activate the venv before running your script?

Comment: Thank you I am doing it now I follow the steps from this website https://programwithus.com/learn/python/pip-virtualenv-windows but when I click on the .bat file a window appears for only one second, is this normal?